# Editing SAS variables with a 2-part hierarchical suffix based on year and month

Tags: date, sas, macros

I am trying to edit variables in a sas dataset. The dataset has multiple types of variables which repeat for quite a few years, each month. The variables are character variables and have names like 'X_1999_01'. The basic idea is that I want to compare 1-2 dates (date1 and date2 below) that each observation might have with the implied dates represented by the variable name (basically the year and month in the name and assuming the first day of the month - 'refdate' below) and adjust the variable if one or more inequalities/equalities between the dates hold (see code). I've created a simple toy dataset below with this structure (including missingness) and show the macro code I have tried. I simplify the data to 2 years and 3 months, but, irl brute force is not an option. If anyone has ideas how to make the macro work or can suggest an alternative approach, it would be much appreciated.

```
data toydata ; 
    input var1999_01 $ var1999_02 $ var1999_03 $ var2000_01 $  
       var2000_02 $ var2000_03 $ date1 : date9. date2 : date9. ;
    format date1 date2 yymmddn8. ;
    datalines ;
    . . . no yes yes 01FEB2000 .
    yes yes yes no no no 01JUL1998 01JAN2000
;
run ;

/* to see the data */
proc print data=toydata ; run ;
proc contents data=toydata ; run ;

%macro failed ;
    data wantdata  ;
        set toydata ;
        %do i=1999 %to 2000 ;
            %let year = &i. ;
            array var&year. [3] $ var&year._01-var&year._03 ;
            %do j=1 %to 3 ;     

                    /*the macro variable refdate is defined based 
                    on the year (i loop) and month (j loop) in the 
                   variable name, assuming 1st day of the month. */

                   
                    %let refdate = %sysfunc(mdy(&j., 1, &year.)) ;

                    /* first condition is whether date1 (a date) is 
                     greater than (i.e., after) the reference date 
                     implied by the variable name, e.g., var1999_01 
                     implies 01Jan1999. */

                    %if date1 > &refdate. %then var&year.[&j.] = 'nye' ;

                    /* the second condition is whether date 2 (if 
                       not missing) is equal to implied date and 
                       then if it's less than (before) the implied 
                       date */

                    %if %length(date2) %then %do ;
                        %if date2 = &refdate. %then var&year.[&j.] = 'event this month' ;
                        %if date2 < &refdate. %then var&year.[&j.] = 'past event' ;
                        %end ;
                %end ;
            %end ;
        run ;
    %mend ;

%failed
```

Comment: I really cannot tell from your description and code what the "condition" is that you are testing.

Comment: Apologies. You are correct. My explanation was confused. I have edited for clarity.

Comment: I am sorry I still do not see what condition you are testing.  Are you not just trying to access the value of the variable that is implied by the value in the DATE variable?  Once you have the value of that implied variable what do you want to do with it?  Are planning to read from that variable or write to it?  If write what do you want to write?  If read what do want to do with the value?

Comment: Note this code makes no sense `%if date1 > &refdate. `  You are asking the macro processor to compare the date value you put into `REFDATE` with the string `date1`.  The macro process cannot see the value of the dataset variable named DATE1 so to it the string date1 is just a string of 5 characters.

Comment: So for each variable of the form var_year_month, e.g., var1999_01, I want to test whether the value of another variable - date1 (a date) - is greater than the date implied by the name, e.g., 1999-01-01 (assuming first of the month). So is date1 > 1999-01-01? If so, I want to change the (character value) of for example var1999_01 (which may be missing) to 'nye' which is short for not yet eligible, but that doesn't really matter. If not, I don't want to change value of variable var1999_01. Similarly for the second set of conditions, I am interested in comparing the variable date2  (also a date).

Comment: 'The macro process cannot see the value of the dataset variable named DATE1 so to it the string date1 is just a string of 5 characters.' Ok. I did not know that as I am new to macros. So is there a way to do just that, i.e., to compare the value of the dataset variable named DATE1 to the macro variable refdate within a macro?

Comment: You use macro logic to generate code.  So show the code you want to generate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To dynamically access a particular variable from a list of variables in a data step you define an array and index into the array.

Since the suffix on the variable names seems to indicate YEAR and MONTH just use INTCK() function to calculate which index to use into the array.

I cannot tell what you are actually trying to do so let's just make something that captures the value of the EVENT variables (the ones with the month encoded into their names) based on month of the current DATE variable being checked.

```
%let basedate='01JAN1999'd;
data want;
  set have ;
  array events $3 var1999_01-var1999_12 var2000_01-var2000_12 ;
  array dates date1-date3 ;
  array event_this_month [3] $3 ;
  do index=1 to dim(dates);
    month = 1 + intck('month',&basedate,dates[index]);
    if 1<=month<=dim(events) then 
      event_this_month[index] = events[month]
    ;
  end;
run;
```

So if DATE1 is in the month DEC_1999 then the value of EVENT_THIS_MONTH1 will be the value of VAR1999_12.

If instead you mean to use the two date variables to indicate a range of months then perhaps you want to run the index month over the set of values implied by those two dates?

So to set all of the variables from DATE1 to DATE2 to the value 'yes' you could use a loop like this:

```
%let basedate='01JAN1999'd;
data want;
  set have ;
  array events $3 var1999_01-var1999_12 var2000_01-var2000_12 ;
  do month=max(1,intck('month',&basedate,date1))
       to  min(dim(events),intck('month',&basedate,date2))
  ;
    events[month] = 'yes';
  end;
run;
```

So in the comments you seem to say that you want to take the index based on the MIN of DATE1 and DATE2 and set the array entries AFTER that to 'nye'.
Given your example data perhaps it is more likely you meant to start from the MAX or the two dates?

Let's try it, first lets fix your example data to have contiguous month variables.

```
data have ; 
  format date1 date2 yymmdd10. ;
  array events $3 var1999_10-var1999_12 var2000_01-var2000_03;
  input var1999_10--var2000_03 date1 :date. date2 :date.;
datalines ;
. . . no yes yes 01FEB2000 .
yes yes yes no no no 01JUL1998 01JAN2000
;
```

Now the base date for the array of date based variables is 01OCT1999

```
%let basedate='01OCT1999'd;
data want;
  set have ;
  array events $3 var1999_10-var1999_12 var2000_01-var2000_03;
  do month=max(1,1+intck('month',&basedate,max(date1,date2))) to dim(events);
    events[month] = 'nye';
  end;
  drop month;
run;
```

Results

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'm struggling to understand your intent also. But usually when you have data values in your variable names (implied dates in this case), that's a sign that life will be easier if you transpose your data into a vertical format. Below takes your data (I added an ID column just for readability), and transposes each row into 6 rows (one per month). Then you should be able to easily do any calculations you want between Date, Date1, and Date2. And you can always transpose back to the wide format if you need that in the end.

```
data toydata ; 
    input ID var1999_01 $ var1999_02 $ var1999_03 $ var2000_01 $  
       var2000_02 $ var2000_03 $ date1 : date9. date2 : date9. ;
    format date1 date2 yymmddn8. ;
    datalines ;
    1 . . . no yes yes 01FEB2000 .
    2 yes yes yes no no no 01JUL1998 01JAN2000
;
run ;

data vert (keep=ID Date Value Date1 Date2);
  set toydata ;
  array vars{*} var:  ;
  do i=1 to dim(vars) ;
    Date=input(compress(vname(vars{i}),'var_'),yymmn6.) ;
    Value=vars{i} ;
    output ;
  end ;
  format Date: date9. ;
run ;

proc print ;
  var Date Value Date1 Date2 ;
  by id ;
  id id ;
run ;
```

Returns:

```
ID         Date    Value        date1        date

 1    01JAN1999             01FEB2000
      01FEB1999             01FEB2000
      01MAR1999             01FEB2000
      01JAN2000     no      01FEB2000
      01FEB2000     yes     01FEB2000
      01MAR2000     yes     01FEB2000


 2    01JAN1999     yes     01JUL1998    01JAN2000
      01FEB1999     yes     01JUL1998    01JAN2000
      01MAR1999     yes     01JUL1998    01JAN2000
      01JAN2000     no      01JUL1998    01JAN2000
      01FEB2000     no      01JUL1998    01JAN2000
      01MAR2000     no      01JUL1998    01JAN2000
```